# If you start as a Bard, can you multiclass to a Cleric with just Multiclass Dabbler?

Tags: dungeon-world

One of my players has an interesting idea for combining a bard and a cleric. He'd start as a bard and become a cleric later. Can he get both the cleric's Commune and Cast a Spell with just one Multiclass Dabbler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you choose a starting move that depends on another starting move for your Multiclass Dabbler choice, you get both. The rules cover this (*Dungeon World*, Chapter 2 “Playing the Game”, § “Character Change”, p. 30):

> The multiclass moves allow you to gain moves from another class. You get to choose any move of your level or lower. For the purpose of multiclassing, **any starting class moves that depend on each other count as one move**—the wizard's cast a spell, spellbook, and prepare spells for example.